# Kafka producer sending invalid characters

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, apache-kafka

Using following code, I send Elasticsearch documents for indexing. I tried converting basic Objects to JSON and sent via producer. However, every message (as checked from the console) appends jibberish characters like - *��t�{"productId":2455*

```
public boolean sendMessage()
{
    PageRequest page = new PageRequest(0, 1); 
    Product p = product.findByName("Cream", page).getContent().get(0);
    String json = "";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        json = mapper.writeValueAsString(p);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }       
    logger.info("JSON = " + json);

    boolean status =  inputToKafka.send(org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder.withPayload(json).build());
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return status;
}
```

Outbound configuration

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:int-kafka="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka/spring-integration-kafka.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <int:channel id="inputToKafka">
        <int:queue/>
    </int:channel>

    <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter
            id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter"
            kafka-producer-context-ref="kafkaProducerContext"
            channel="inputToKafka">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="1000" time-unit="MILLISECONDS" receive-timeout="0" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
    </int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>

    <task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="5" keep-alive="120" queue-capacity="500"/>

    <int-kafka:producer-context id="kafkaProducerContext">
        <int-kafka:producer-configurations>
            <int-kafka:producer-configuration broker-list="localhost:9092"
                                              topic="test_topic"
                                              compression-codec="default"/>
        </int-kafka:producer-configurations>
    </int-kafka:producer-context>

    </beans>
```

Any clue ?

Plugin used: [Spring Extension Kafka](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced this issue today and got it resolved by setting correct value-serializer class in the producer configuration as shown below:

```
<int-kafka:producer-configuration
                broker-list="localhost:9092" topic="headers['kafka_topic']"
                key-class-type="java.lang.String" value-class-type="java.lang.String"
                key-serializer="kafkaSerializer" value-serializer="kafkaSerializer"/>

<bean id="kafkaSerializer" class="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Those could be tab characters (because of indented JSON) that your console doesn't interpret well.

If you disable the indentation of the output generated by the object mapper, those characters might go away.

```
try {
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);     <---- add this line
    json = mapper.writeValueAsString(p);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Val, but even after adding given line, same output is being returned. Any more ideas ?

Comment: Any way to set a breakpoint after generating the JSON (e.g. on the `logger.info()` line) and see what's in the JSON string? Also does your Kafka consumer also see bad characters or is it just in your console?

Comment: Getting bad characters at the consumer end, which returns JSON parsing error. `logger.info()` returns proper string for variable _json_. I am guessing these characters are appended after the payload is built.

Comment: Do you have some stack trace from the consumer end telling us more about the JSON parsing error?

Comment: `05/Oct/2015:15:54:29:374 +0530 [main] ERROR o.e.kafka.consumer.MessageHandler - Failed Message #1: MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character ('¬' (code 172)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: [B@4dd7edb0; line: 1, column: 2]];`

Answer (score 0):

Kafka does not do such things. Debug at your String message which you are sending it to Kafka producer.
If you are getting this message from URL or HTML form, You may want to decode your message first, before sending to producer.

e.g. URLDecoder.decode(message, "UTF-8")