# Unexpected character in Kafka message with Flume

Tags: apache-kafka, cloudera, kafka-consumer-api, flume, flume-ng

I have an ingestion pipeline using Flume & Kafka, consuming CSV files, converting events in JSON in a Flume Interceptor and pushing it in Kafka.

When I'm logging the message before being sent to Kafka, it's a normal, valid JSON. But when consuming the same message from Kafka, I'm getting errors when trying to serialize it, saying it's not valid JSON.

Indeed I have unrecognized chars at the beginning of my message:

e.g. �

I think it stands for the empty header that flume try to had to the event when posting to Kafka. But I can't seem to be able to prevent this from happening.

Does anyone knows how to completely remove headers from Flume events being sent or more precisely, remove those chars ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a basic character encoding issue, like if kafka runs on Linux while the producer runs on a windows machine. You might want to triple-check that all machines handle utf-8 encoded messages.

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933355/kafka-producer-sending-invalid-characters) should be your friend.

Comment: I thought as well at first but I triple checked and everything is UTF-8 encoded. I made some test and that's really a char added by flume when posting the event to the kafka channel...

Comment: Well that's a pity. Have you tried to introduce an(other) value-serializer as mentioned in the linked post? Could you post the producer-configuration? Also, which kafka version are you using?

Comment: did you solve this issue? I am facing the same problem right now